# Deriving Wave Function for Scattering States with Delta-Function Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, normalization

I am following the Griffiths Book on Quantum Mechanics, and am following the derivation for the wave function for Delta-Function Potentials.

$$V(x) = -\alpha \delta(x)$$

In the scattering states, where $E > 0$, when solving the Schrodinger Equation in the range $x < 0$, we are left with

$$ \psi(x) = Ae^{i\kappa x} + Be^{-i\kappa x}, \text{   where } \kappa \equiv \frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar} $$

Whereas in the boundstate, we had the $Ae^{-\kappa x}$ term having to be zero due to the blow-up at -infinity, why do we not have the same problem here? The book states: "this time we cannot rule out either term, since neither of them blows up." Isn't the -infinity still blowing up for the $B$ term?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange Physics! Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See our [meta site](//meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5958) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Comment: Notice the factor of $i$ in the exponent: those are complex exponentials, which always have modulus 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither one of the terms blow up because of the complex exponential. This exponential is real for the bound state case.